# How can i collapse view when list is scroll?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

In my project i am using listview, my requirement is when i was click in my list item view is expanded, and click another view in same listview previous expanded view is collapsed or when i was scroll listview any expanded view is collapsed.

How can i resolve?

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new AdapterView
        .OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
          ExpandableListItem viewObject = (ExpandableListItem)getItemAtPosition(getPositionForView
                (view));
        if (!viewObject.isExpanded()) {

            if(exview!=null)
            {
                 collapseView(exview);

            }

           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    expandView(view);
                    exview = view;              
            }
               }, 500);                  

        } else {
             exview=null;
            collapseView(view);
        }
        /*if (!viewObject.isExpanded()) {
            expandView(view);
        } else {
            collapseView(view);
        }*/
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: how can I collapse if already expanding the view in listview when listview is scrolling?